# Wordpress caching and redirecting to old URL for any pages other than homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I have a Wordpress development setup with MAMP and Browsersync, and this is pointing to localhost:3000

In order to develop on mobile, I have changed the site URL, to my IP address, XX.XX.XX.XX:3000

This works when I visit the homepage, and when I visit the /wp-admin URL, or when I visit the /wp-json URL's, however, when I try to visit a site page other than the homepage directly, it ALWAYS redirects back to localhost (ie. if I visit http://XX.XX.XX.XX:3000/about, it will redirect to http://localhost:3000/about). When I visit the homepage first, and then link to pages this works (it's handled by React but it does call the API correctly to the correct address)

I need to be able to visit pages directly, for debugging reasons. I have had it working before but for some reason it seems to be caching URL's now.

I have tried the following:

- Setting WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in wp-config
- Changing all the URL's in my database, in any place where the old URL was set
  – Resetting permalinks in wp-admin
  – Making changes to the pages in question and saving them
  – Clearing browser cache
  – Restarting MAMP and Browsersync
  – Setting PLL_CACHE_HOME_URL to false
  – Setting RELOCATE to true
  – Clearing the WP Cache
  – Making sure MAMP has PHP Cache turned off

Does anyone know what is causing this? From looking at my database I can't see any references to the old site url anywhere. Does MAMP have some cache settings it's possible to clear?

Comment: you are browsing the xx.xx.xx.xx in same system or different system, and make sure that your ip address is a network ip address if you are browsing from different system, if it is in same system ,then 127.0.0.1:3000 is enough

Comment: The IP address is working, it's just the fact that Wordpress keeps redirecting to an the old IP address from a previous session

Comment: then its a cache problem, try in different browser

Comment: yes tried in all different browsers and cleared cache